# to update multiple nested array using array filter not working in mongoose

Tags: arrays, mongoose, filter, subdocument

I am using nodeJS with mongoldb 3.6.4. I have tried the Arrayfilter to update nested subdocument. But it is not updating the value. Here is the sample code I tried ( after incorporating the comments from Anthony Winzlet to make asyn Call)

```
    var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
    var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var DrugRefSchema   = new Schema({
    drugRefs: [{
    refName: String,
    drugs: [{   
      name: String,
      drugType:String,
    }]
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('DrugRef', DrugRefSchema);

async function UpdateMedList () {
    const out = await DrugRef.aggregate([
    { $unwind:  '$drugRefs'},
    { $unwind:  '$drugRefs.drugs'},
    { $project : { refName:'$drugRefs.refName', med:'$drugRefs.drugs.name',_id:0}},
    { $group: {_id: { med: '$med',refName:'$refName'}}},
    { $project : { med:'$_id.med', refName:'$_id.refName',_id:0}},
    ])

    out.map(async(data) => {
        var refName=data.refName;
        var oldName=data.med;
        var newName=oldName.trim();

       const updateName = await DrugRef.update(
           { },
           { $set:{"drugRefs.$[i].drugs.$[j].name":newName}},
           { arrayFilters: [ { "i.refName": refName },{ "j.name": oldName }], "multi": true }
           )

       console.log("Orig:'"+oldName+"': to be updated:'"+newName+"':");
       console.log("update Result:"+JSON.stringify(updateName));

    })
}
```

and name is not getting changed still. pl help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with mongoose version. It was 4.3. When I upgraded to 5.x it started working. 
Also when I upgraded with npm install mongoose with -g option it upgraded to 5.3.0 but my module mongoose was still pointing to 4.3. Then I had to install mongoose without -g also